# What is the orientation of the normalized boundary $\partial(M\times N)$ of product manifold?

Tags: manifolds, manifolds-with-boundary, cobordism

Assume $M$ and $N$ are two oriented smooth manifold with or without boundaries. Then $M\times N$ is an oriented manifold with corners. Inspired by the theory of cobordism or differential forms, the *normalized boundary* $$
\partial(M\times N)=\partial M\times N \sqcup (-1)^n M\times \partial N$$
could possibly involve an orientation reversing, like $n=\dim M$ or $\dim M-1$.

What should be the right orientation convention?

Moreover, it is very interesting to ask what is $\partial (M_1\times M_2\times \cdots \times M_k)$?

Comment: If both $M$ and $N$ have boundary, then $M\times N$ is *not* a manifold with boundary.

Comment: @TedShifrin You are right, let's say it is a manifold with corners and we consider the *normalized* boundary: for example, the normalized boundary of $[0,1]\times [0,1]$ should be some copies of $[0,1]$, although the `boundary' of it is actually not a manifold.

Comment: Yes, $(-1)^{\dim M}$ is the correct sign. You can check this with simplices, for example, and taking $N=[0,1]$ is always a good example.

Comment: @TedShifrin I see. That's a good point. Thank you.